# Azure Console fails any command and shows code containing "Invalid value for encodingHint"

Tags: api, azure, web-services, cloud

Any command I execute from the web-based **portal.azure.com** for my application service's console throws the following error:

`D:\home\site\wwwroot>dir`

`function(e){if(void 0===e&&(e="legacy"),this._body instanceof b)return this._body.toString();if(this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer)switch(e){case"legacy":return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint16Array(this._body));case"iso-8859":return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint8Array(this._body));default:throw new Error("Invalid value for encodingHint: "+e)}return null==this._body?"":"object"==typeof this._body?JSON.stringify(this._body,null,2):this._body.toString()}`

It then completely hangs. I've been searching for a solution but this issue doesn't seem to have been reported.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting the storage linked to your console instance?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but don't have a storage connected. did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a new API app (the resource I was trying to deploy to) and switching to it.

One comment suggested reconnecting the storage, but my resource didn't have one.

Call it blue-green deployment if you want to feel better about using this hack.